# Getting the torch to glow?

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview

My objective is as simple as to have my own flashlight app; I have researched both the android developer site and stackoverflow quite thoroughly but seem to lack the connecting bits:

```
package my.torch;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

/* public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}
*/


Camera mCamera;
CompoundButton mTorch;
Parameters camParams;
private Context context;
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
AlertDialog alertDialog;
public  SurfaceView surfaceView;
public  SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
public String flashMode = null;



/** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.mysurface);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();

    context = MainActivity.this;
    if(context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
        PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)){
        mTorch = (CompoundButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);

    }
    else{
        // should use Dialog
        // tell the user that he has no camera
        //showDialog(context, FLASH_NOT_SUPPORTED);
    }

    final Camera mCamera = Camera.open(0);

    mTorch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                Log.e("mTorch", "on");
                Parameters camParams = mCamera.getParameters();
                // params.setFlashMode( Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF )
                camParams.setFlashMode( Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                mCamera.setParameters(camParams);

                mCamera.startPreview();
                flashMode = camParams.getFlashMode();
                Log.e("mTorch", flashMode );
                // The toggle is enabled


            } else {
                // The toggle is disabled
                Log.e("mTorch", "off");
                Parameters camParams = mCamera.getParameters();
                // params.setFlashMode( Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF )
                camParams.setFlashMode( Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                mCamera.setParameters(camParams);
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                flashMode = camParams.getFlashMode();
                Log.e("mTorch", flashMode );


            }
        }
    });

    //mCamera.release();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mCamera != null) {
      camParams.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
      mCamera.setParameters(camParams);
      mCamera.stopPreview();
      mCamera.release();
    }
}

}
```

The logging happily reports that the flashmode is torch or off as intended, however: The flash does not torch at all. 
I read that I needed a surfaceview so I added it but with 0 height.

As I did collect bits and pieces here and there the code is probably not beautiful, my apologies.

Any idea on what I'm missing out?

(this is for a Nexus 5, 4.4.2)

Comment: Did you add camera permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add permission to access camera in your manifest file?

> uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"